# How to call a method that doesn't return anything?

Tags: java

I'm trying to call this method that enters a coordinate point from user input.

```
public class Cases {

public static Result Case1(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter index: ");
    int i = in.nextInt(); //validate
    System.out.print("Enter integers x, y to replace: ");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int y = in.nextInt();
    A[i] = new Point(x, y);

    if(occupancy<i)
        occupancy=i;
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to make it work since it doesn't need a return statement.

This is how I called it from my main method:

```
Result r = null;
r = Cases.Case1();
```

I want all of my cases from a switch statement into this separate method, but I can't even get one of them to work. What am I missing?

Comment: Edit: sorry, I think you *do* need a return statement here, that may be the problem.  (Yes, my compiler says "missing return statement."  Also A and occupancy are undefined.)

Comment: `Cases.Case1()` does return a `Result` object. It won't compile that way. You should change the return type to `void` and change the way you call it (you do not have to assign it to a reference variable.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a structure of declaring methods in Java. From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

> ... method declarations have six components, in order:
>
> 1. Modifiers—such as public, private, and others you will learn about
>      later.
> 2. The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method,
>      or void if the method does not return a value.
> 3. The method name—the rules for field names apply to method names as
>      well, but the convention is a little different.
> 4. The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input
>      parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by parentheses,
>      (). If there are no parameters, you must use empty parentheses.
> 5. An exception list—to be discussed later.
> 6. The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code,
>      including the declaration of local variables, goes here.

So, if you need to declare method without any return type, you need to write `void` in second position.

In your code

```
public static Result Case1(){
```

there is return type `Result` that you need to return. If don't want to return it - declare method like this:

```
public static void Case1(){
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring a method that shouldn't return anything you must use *void* as the return type.
In your case the return type is *Result* so it won't compile until you add a return statement returning a Result object.
More on defining methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html